# Hover event does not target children

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a simple navbar and when a user hovers over a `<li>` tag it must turn red. When the user removes their cursor it must turn grey. It works but not properly. Inside `<li>` tags I have `<Link>` provided by `react-router-dom` and when I target `<li>` tag it works properly but when I target `<Link>` it does not work on parent tag (`<li>`).

Here is my code:

Navbar.js:

```
  return(
    <nav className={this.props.navClass}>
      <ul>
        <li
          className="main"
          style={{transitionDuration: "0.9s"}}
          onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}
        >
          <Link to="/">მთავარი</Link>
        </li>
        <li
          className="aboutUs"
        >
          <Link
            to="/about-us"
            onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}
          >ჩვენს შესახებ</Link></li>
        <li
          className="contactUs"
          onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}
        >
          <Link to="/contact">დაგვეკონტაქტე</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
```

Main.js:

```
  hover(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }

  mouseLeave(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey'
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="navBar">
          <Navbar
            navClass="navbar"
            mouseEnter={this.hover.bind(this)}
            mouseLeave={this.mouseLeave.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

How can I fix it?

By the way, I will be glad if you tell me if I am breaking UI in different components correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: why aren't you using CSS selectors to handle styling?

Comment: it is for testing of course. but i still need to know it

Answer (score 0):

you could add `link{pointer-events:none}` to your css.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the Navbar component you need to wrap up your Links inside Router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

return (
        <nav className={this.props.navClass}>
            <Router>
                <ul>
                    <li className="main" style={{transitionDuration: "0.9s"}} onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}>
                        <Link to="/">მთავარი</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="aboutUs">
                        <Link to="/about-us" onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}>ჩვენს შესახებ</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="contactUs" onMouseEnter={this.props.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.props.mouseLeave}>
                        <Link to="/contact">დაგვეკონტაქტე</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </Router>
        </nav>
    );
```

The above code works fine, in the second `<li className="aboutUs"></li>` the reason that only `<Link />` component is highlighted and not its parent (li) is that Link component equivalents to `<a></a>` and its display is inline.
If you add the following css, the parent li is also highlighted.

```
a {display: block;}
```